# Is there a formula for the coefficients in the expansion of $\frac1{e}(1+1/x)^x$?

Tags: logarithms, power-series, exponential-function

Is there a formula for the coefficients in the expansion of $\frac1{e}(1+1/x)^x$ as
$x \to \infty$?

This is inspired by
[Evaluate: $ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e+\dfrac{1}{2}ex}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291560/evaluate-lim-x-to-0-frac1x1-x-e-dfrac12exx2)

According to Wolfy,
the first few terms are

$1 - 1/(2 x) + (11 )/(24 x^2) - (7 )/(16 x^3) + O((1/x)^4)
$.

Is there a not too complex formula,
possibly involving some
nested summations,
for the expansion

$\frac1{e}(1+1/x)^x
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n/x^n
$?

I would not be surprised if 
this has been asked before,
but it did not appear
in the list of similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formula for such coefficients $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is given in terms of [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind):
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{s(n+k,k)}{(n+k)!}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}$$
See [OEIS-A055505](https://oeis.org/A055505) for references. The first terms are
$$1, -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{11}{24}, -\frac{7}{16}, \frac{2447}{5760}, -\frac{959}{2304}, \frac{238043}{580608}, -\frac{67223}{165888}, \frac{559440199}{1393459200},\dots$$